# Getting more than 0.5W from USB OTG

Tags: power, usb-host, usb-otg

Has anyone actually measured the maximum amount of power that can be drawn from a smartphone's (say Samsung S4) USB OTG in host mode?

I've read people suggest 100mA but can't find if anyone has actually tested it. I have seen it work with a keyboard, mouse and both keyboard & mouse but these are only around 50mA.

If I need say 1W for 2 minutes, is there any way to make it possible (without the use of additional batteries)?

Comment: If you can store energy you can power a boiler... It would take some time. Just explain what you have in your mind so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks. I meant no batteries. But other components say capacitor is ok.

Comment: Well 1W for two minutes is 120J, at 5Vdc that's 6000F. You will need to go up in voltage, and then back down.

Comment: That's a massive capacitor! Is there any other options (that's smaller & low cost)?

Comment: Yes, step up voltage, charge a smaller cap, step it back down. But that's not trivial nor small... please tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I made an error that's 9.6F, quite big anyway.

Comment: I am trying to use a smartphone as power source to a uvc lamp. Something small and compact for travel but need more power for the lamp.

Comment: It's not solving your question as you asked it, but since you're willing to power this from USB, maybe consider looking into USB battery packs.  They're essentially lithium polymer batteries with a support circuit to charge off USB and output USB.  They're pretty cheap, and have a much higher capacity than most smartphones.  Checking the one in my pocket, we're sitting at 5000mAh with 5V, 1.5A maximum ratings.

Comment: Hi Phox, thanks for the comment. That's a good suggestion. Could be a fall back/stop gap option. Much appreciated. :)